# Filesystem cant copy files because they open in another program c++

Tags: c++, windows, file, filesystems

As you can see by the title I have issues when copying files from a directory to another. The code works perfectly fine but when the files are in use, obviously I get an error. Is there any way I can skip these files? (that are in use) and simply move on to the next?

I have tried looking for a solution to my issue but it seems there isn't a function from what I've seen on the internet for filesystem, any information given helps. I provided the code below for copying files.

```
std::filesystem::copy("C:\\Users\\"+ user+"\\AppData\\Local\\tee\\test\\User Data", "C:\\Users\\"+user+"\\AppData\\Local\\tee\\test\\Application", std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing | std::filesystem::copy_options::recursive);
```

Comment: If your operating system doesn't allow files to be copied when in use, as part of its basic security foundation, or technical foundation, there's nothing that `std::filesystem::copy()` will be able to do about it.

Comment: There is a windows function to skip the file, thats what im trying to do. for example: 

https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/img_54ef5249364a8.png?trim=1,1&bg-color=000&pad=1,1

Comment: You could use [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) if you don't care about cross-platform support. As an aside, you shouldn't be manually conducting your file paths. Instead, query the system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't copy you will get an exception, if you don't catch that the program chrashes. You can skip the files if you catch the exception with a simple try-catch statement. eg.:

```
try{
    std::filesystem::copy(/*Params*/);
}catch(...){
    std::cout<<"cant-copy '"<<filename<<"'";
    /*Handle it if you don't want to just ignore (sleep and try later or ask the user what to to...)*/
}
```

Comment: I understand your answer and it would work great for some cases, but in my case, I need to skip and move on to the next file its copying, how would I achieve it?

Comment: Assuming your copy is in a loop, `continue;`.

Comment: There is no loop, we just use the recursive option.

Comment: Can I see your copying function, so I can be more specific how to fix it?